# What does it mean by conformal group act projectively and unitarily?

Tags: mathematical-physics, definition, conformal-field-theory

What does it mean by conformal group act projectively, unitarily, and projective unitarily?

Comment: @flippiefanus it occurred during the studying of 2d CFT, where, during operator product expansion of $\hat{T}(z)\hat{T}(w)$, quote:"the coefficient $c$ of $\frac{c/2}{(z-w)^4}$... basically saying that $conf(\mathbb{R})$ was allowed to act projectively."

Comment: Do you understand what a [unitary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_representation) of a group is? Do you understand what a [projective representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) of a group is? These concepts are independent of the conformal group.

Comment: @G.Smith Yeah, but CFT in 2D wasn't always unitary.

Comment: Hi ShoutOutAndCalculate: If the definitions provided above by @G.Smith don't answer your question, what answer are you looking for?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry, I was new to the topic, here's what I learned.(in 2D CFT) 1. Unlike the usual QFT, $conf(R)$ in CFT was not always unitary representation. 2. CFT was also sometime "allowed to be projectively'.(which seemed to indicate that CFT was not always projectively either). Thus, I wasn't quite sure what's the physical consequence of "allowing" $conf(R)$ of CFT to be unitary or projectively, or both.

Comment: To reopen this post (v1) please make clear (in the post, not just in comments) what you already know and what you're asking.